# Make bottom sheet(popover) sticky to button (Angular material)

Tags: css, angular, sass, angular-material

I have project in angular, i add bottom sheet from angular material and it work.
i try to make the opened popup be sticky to botton and responsive to him But its not work.

my main components:

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { MatBottomSheet } from '@angular/material/bottom-sheet';
import { PopupsDialogComponent } from '../../../modules/home/components/popups-dialog/popups-dialog.component';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-header',
  templateUrl: './header.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./header.component.sass']
})
export class HeaderComponent implements OnInit {

  constructor(private _bottomSheet: MatBottomSheet) { }

  ngOnInit() {
  }
  openBottomSheet(): void {
    this._bottomSheet.open(PopupsDialogComponent, {
      panelClass: 'custom-popup'
    });
  }
}
```

main components html:
This the button that i want the dialog be stiky to him

```
<header>
  <div class="container">
    <button mat-fab class="mat-success" (click)=openBottomSheet()>+</button>
  </div>
</header>
```

PopupsDialogComponents:

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import {MatBottomSheetRef} from '@angular/material/bottom-sheet';
@Component({
  selector: 'app-popups-dialog',
  templateUrl: './popups-dialog.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./popups-dialog.component.sass']
})
export class PopupsDialogComponent {

  constructor(private _bottomSheetRef: MatBottomSheetRef<PopupsDialogComponent>) {}

  openLink(event: MouseEvent): void {
    this._bottomSheetRef.dismiss();
    event.preventDefault();
  }

}
```

style.css:

```
.custom-popup
    position: absolute
    top: 95px
    right: 26%
    min-width: 0% !important
```

thanks a lot

Comment: Have you imported the following in your main sass/css file?(src/style.sass or css)
`@import '~@angular/material/prebuilt-themes/deeppurple-amber.css'`

Comment: you are applying styles to top:95px so it will be positioned there, what's the problem?

Comment: Oh you mean to button not bottom...  
(you have a few mistakes in your question) . 
I have added to few lines the src/main.css
`.mat-bottom-sheet-container{
      position: fixed !important;
      top: 27px !important;
      left: 0px !important;
}`

Comment: When i resize the screen the popup get new position ;(

Comment: Instead of fixed use absolute

Answer (score 0):

Some of built-in angular components are rendered lately,
I think you can handle that in **CSS** like:

```
:host ::ng-deep .custom-popup {
    position: absolute
    top: 95px
    right: 26%
    min-width: 0% !important
}
```

Comment: In angular 8 this is deprecated. https://angular.io/guide/component-styles#deprecated-deep--and-ng-deep